# jQuery can't use addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two DIVS and for simplicity's sake, I'll put them here...

```
<div id="div1"></div>

<div id="maincontent" class="extra">

.... some content goes here...

</div>
```

So here's the challenge and it's probably quite simply, actually.

DIV1 is being populated by the JQuery .load event and displays first.

Then after 30 secs, and the HTML video runs, it the JQuery .fadeOut occurs and then DIV maincontent has the .fadeIn event executed on it.

At least that's how its "supposed" to work.

Here's the JS code.

```
$(function() {
    $("#maincontent").addClass("hidden");
    $("#div1").delay(35000).fadeOut("slow");
    $("#maincontent").delay(36500).fadeIn("slow");
    $("#maincontent").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

There's another class that's simply .hidden with a display: none:

but, maincontent div isn't hiding and is there while div1 is!

div1 fades out nicely, but maincontent is there the whole time.

here's the css class: .extra

```
.extra {min-width:1000px;min-height:100%; height:auto !important; height:100%; margin: 0 auto 0px; overflow:hidden; position:relative; z-index:10; background: url(../images/bgwithTitle.png) center center no-repeat;}
```

So I need to probably have the DOM exist first before I try to add the class .hidden to the maincontent div, correct?

See, the other problem is, if I add, .hidden to the div class for maincontent, .extra doesn't work either.

Comment: Instead of applying a class `hidden`, why not just use `$('#maincontent').hide();`?

Comment: `fadeIn()` fades in an element(thus showing it), while `fadeOut()` fades out an element(thus hiding it).

Answer (score 3):

It is because the functions aren't being run through in order. Try nesting the functions in the callbacks of the previous function -

```
$(function() {
    $("#div1").delay(35000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $("#maincontent").delay(36500).fadeIn("slow", function() {
            $(this).addClass('.extra'); // or we can add specific CSS properties
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT: note the removal of the `.hide()` and / or `.addClass('hidden')`. Hide `#maincontent` in the CSS with `#maincontent { display: none; }`

Comment: OK, this works except for one small thing.  The .extra CSS class above, isn't working "if" apply the .hide function.  When I take it out, the .extra CSS class works but the #maincontent div is now exposed. Hmmmm. Six of one and a half dozen of the other.  We're close.

Comment: What is in your `hidden` class?

Comment: it's simply .hidden { display: none; }

Comment: That is what `.hide()` does, sets `display` to `none` on the element(s) it is called on. Can you setup a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: What is the 'extra' CSS class?

Comment: The CSS extra class is shown above. I can't show a fiddle because the website is for a new TV show.  But I'll try and dumb it down... so as not to expose anything.  Bottom line, when the .hide() or .hidden class is applied, the .extra class does not work.  There is a popup or modal that has text in it and when the .hide() or .hidden class is applied the content in the modal is reduced to 100px and not 100%. Something funky is going on because when I remove the first line of code: $("#maincontent").hide(), everything works fine except maincontent is now exposed while div1 is running.

Comment: `.extra` doesn't work on `#maincontent` when hidden because it is not displayed. You would be better off hiding your `#maincontent` in CSS (rather than the first line of jQuery) and then showing that div as I have shown here. When it is shown it should get its CSS properly. If not we can add the CSS to it as I will be showing in my code edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54538/discussion-between-peter-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: @Peter I am unable to chat from this computer (work rules, they have blocked that URL).

Comment: I setup a fiddle based on the absolute minimums here and it all seems to work well - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/ELYAR/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is asynchronous, so doesn't wait for delay to be complete to removeClass.
You must register a callback function, which will be called after delay and fadeIn/Out.

```
...
$("#maincontent").addClass("hidden");
$("#div1").delay(35000).fadeOut("slow", function(){
    $("#maincontent").delay(36500).fadeIn("slow", function(){
        $("#maincontent").removeClass("hidden");
    });
});
...
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: OK, this works except for one small thing. The .extra CSS class above, isn't working "if" apply the .hidden class. When I take it out, the .extra CSS class works but the #maincontent div is now exposed. Hmmmm. Six of one and a half dozen of the other. We're close